# Extending IEnumerable: How do I return the last not string.empty element?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, generic-collections

I want to create an extension method of class IEnumerable and create a method that retrieves the last item in the collection that is not *string.empty*. The collection will be **always** an array and the returned value a string.

I consider a null value an empty string.

I don't know how to do this in a *generics* way. I wonder if I should make it a generic method since the type will be an array of string.

I will call this function like this:

```
 string s = myArray.LastNotEmpty<???>();
```

How can I face this?

```
static class Enumerable
{
    public static TSource LastNotEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect this to do if it's not a sequence of strings?

Comment: It will be always an array of strings. I wonder if I should make it a generic method.

Comment: @senyortoni: If it's always an array of strings, what's the purpose of using a generic method?

Comment: @recursive In fact the generics is not a must. Post updated.

Comment: @senyortoni What if an item is null, is this considered empty or non empty?

Comment: @BobVale Good question. It should be never a null value but... It's considered an empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static TSource LastNotEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) where TSource:String
    {
        return source.LastOrDefault(x=>!string.isNullOrEmpty(x));
    }
}
```

or more specific

```
static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static string LastNotEmpty(this IEnumerable<string> source) 
    {
        return source.LastOrDefault(x=>!string.isNullOrEmpty(x));
    }
}
```

As stated in other answers, Enumerable already exists in the System.Linq namespace so the static class has been named differently here.

You then just make sure that your calling code has a `using` for the namespace of this class and then just use

```
string s = myArray.LastNotEmpty();
```

`s` will equal null if there are no occurrences.

The above calling method could be used by either implementation of LastNotEmpty as the GenericType arugments could be worked out by the compiler.

**The updates below this line are not needed to answer the question they are just provided as alternative solutions for a more generic approach**

**UPDATE - Just to please Recursive who wanted a fully generic solution. The OP has already stated that the collection will always be strings but...**

```
static class MyEnumerable {
  public static string LastNotEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source==null) return null;  // Deals with null collection
    return source.OfType<string>().LastOrDefault(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x);
  }
}
```

This will first filter the collection to those of type string.  The result will be `null` if the collection is null or if there are no results found..

**UPDATE Again - This is only to try and make Recursive feel good :)**

This version will return the first `TSource` that is not equal to either the empty string or null. The `ReferenceEquals` is used because resharper complains about comparing a possible value type with null...

```
static class MyEnumerable {
  public static TSource LastNotEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source==null) return null;  // Deals with null collection
    return source.LasdtOrDefault(x=>
                                    !ReferenceEquals(x,null)
                                    &&
                                    !x.Equals(String.Empty)
                                 );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because there's an out-of-the box method that can do this.

Comment: @Rawling - yeah, because that's really answering the OP's question.

Comment: @Matt Exactly! Or was that sarcasm?

Comment: This is for `IEnumerable<string>`, not an arbitrary generic parameter like was asked in the question.

Comment: @recursive OP may be confused, says it's always an array of strings in a comment,

Comment: @recursive The OP said he wants the method to work on a sequence of strings, he simply used a generic method in his attempt at solving the problem; it wasn't listed as a requirement.  Additionally, making the method generic has no purpose.  String is sealed, so you couldn't extend it anyway.

Comment: @BobVale: I'm not sure if I'm capable of being happy about this question. :)  But your updated answer returns the last string that's not an empty string.  If, for example, the last element in `source` is not a string, then my understanding of the question was that element should be returned, since it is not an empty string.

Comment: @BobVale: Yes! I am finally happy!  And it feels great.  It seems I misunderstood the question originally, but thanks for humoring me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an `IEnumerable<string>`, you can just call

```
string lastNotEmpty = myIEnumerableString.Last(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549138.aspx).

Comment: Of course the interesting question is what if the last elements is null. OP didn't really state what to do about null!

Comment: I totally missed the "I consider a null value as empty", didn't I?